# Deserialize JSON into a binary file using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-services

I have the following string:

> 'UEsDBAoAAAAAALi8T0+jHCkcDAAAAAwAAAAMAAAASUJNX0RhdGEudHh0SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhUEsBAj8ACgAAAAAAuLxPT6McKRwMAAAADAAAAAwAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAElCTV9EYXRhLnR4dAoAIAAAAAAAAQAYADZQuhPTg9UB2UqCCNOD1QHZSoII04PVAVBLBQYAAAAAAQABAF4AAAA2AAAAAAA='

This text file is a small zip file serialized using JSON. How can I create the original zip file from this sequence of string using Python?

TIA

Comment: this is not a valid json although

Comment: That looks like base64. Use the base64 module to decode the string, than you either write the content to the disk or use BytesIO or StringIO to "simulate" a file and the zip module to unpack it.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base64 encode a zip file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511705/base64-encode-a-zip-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the base64 encoding of the contents of a zip file. You can turn it into a file with this.

```
s = 'UEsDBAoAAAAAALi8T0+jHCkcDAAAAAwAAAAMAAAASUJNX0RhdGEudHh0SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhUEsBAj8ACgAAAAAAuLxPT6McKRwMAAAADAAAAAwAJAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAElCTV9EYXRhLnR4dAoAIAAAAAAAAQAYADZQuhPTg9UB2UqCCNOD1QHZSoII04PVAVBLBQYAAAAAAQABAF4AAAA2AAAAAAA='
import base64

bin = base64.b64decode(s)
with open('temp.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bin)
```

Once this is run, open the file up with your favorite zip-file opener and you get one file called `IBM_DATA.txt` with the contents:

```
Hello World!
```